# Javascript: How to rewrite links inside a webcomponent shadow dom?

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom

So, I whipped up something that's really only useful for me personally. I have a game that outputs some tables as markdown files, and I wanted to be able to view them easily as tables.

So I'm using a module called zero-markdown to just wrap those on my webserver. It works, but unfortunately there are links from one file to another, which are filename.md which would open that md file directly. I want those to be changed to filename.html so that I can have them be rendered properly. I can just change the md file with sed, but that's not something I want to have to do every time I export these.

So I got myself a little javascript snippet that works for changing those links, in theory:

```js
for (var link of document.links) {
    if (link.href.indexOf("quirks.md") > -1) {
        var pieces = link.href.split("quirks.md");
        link.href = pieces[0] + "quirks.html" + pieces[1];
    }
}
```

I've run that in jfiddle and it works. But it wouldn't on my page. A bunch of experimentation with the browser console and console log statements and I realized that document.links is empty. A little further research revealed that this is because the module creates a shadow dom to put the translated tables in.

I'm no Javascript guy, I barely code anything these days, so I have no idea how to reach into the shadow dom to accomplish this. Any help?

Comment: You really should do this on the server side anyway, either before or after the zero-markdown translation

Comment: I mean, probably, but I really don't want to dust off my php and I don't want to run a sed script on the source data if I don't have to. So I was hoping to just quickly knock this out in pure javascript, and frankly at this point I've sunk a few hours into trying to figure it out so I *have* to solve it :D

TBH I could just not do this project at all and install a markdown viewer extension in chrome if I were gonna do it the easy way.

Comment: Find the host node of the shadow dom root and then `host.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('a')` instead of `document.links`.

Comment: @kellyMurphy Oh wait I missed that zero-markdown is running in the browser anyway, so ignore my first comment.

Comment: Btw zero-markdown appears to load the referenced markdown document asynchronously to embed it, so you might have a hard time running your replacement script at the right time. You'd need to detect when the links are being created.

Comment: If you create your own Web Component _**extended**_ from ``zero-markdown``, you can run all your own code in the ``connectedCallback`` **after** ``zero-markdown`` did its work.... But.... that requires learning some serious JavaScript, there is no _quickly knock this out_ in programming.